# Save file and rename old version

Tags: python, windows, file, file-io, filenames

I have pickled (dumped) my model and saved it for use in a web application. Each time I re-run analysis of the model, the file is pickled again and saved in the same folder under the (file name + date). In case the new file is created on the same day as the last version I would like to rename the old version.

I attempted to rename the old file by adding `'_archived'` to the end. The code below correctly creates a new file when none exists but when file already exists re-running it removes old file and throws error.

```
path = r'C:\scoring_model'
dest = os.path.join(path, 'test12')

now = pd.datetime.now()
date_now = str(now.date())    
model_name = 'model' + '_' + date_now
model_loc = os.path.join(dest, model_name)

if os.path.exists(model_loc):    
    try:
        os.rename(model_loc, model_name + '_archived')

    except:
        os.remove(model_loc)
        os.rename(model_loc, model_name + '_archived')
        with open(model_loc, 'wb') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(scoring_model, pfile)

else:
    with open(model_loc, 'wb') as pfile:
        pickle.dump(scoring_model, pfile)
```

I get the following error:

```
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-c132203d92f3> in <module>()
     16     except:
     17         os.remove(model_loc)
---> 18         os.rename(model_loc, model_name + '_archived')
     19         with open(model_loc, 'wb') as pfile:
     20             pickle.dump(scoring_model, pfile)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the given file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are calling `os.rename()` just after calling `os.remove()`. In Windows, trying to rename a file which does not exist will raise an exception in Python.

Comment: as mentioned below responding to Kevin, when removing `os.remove(model_loc)` i get a different error

Comment: @figgy I'll be able to help you properly only if you explain clearly exactly what is it that you want to achieve? Your current question does not convey that properly. For example, if the current filename is abc and you run the program, do you want it to get renamed to abc_archived and the new file to be named abc? If yes, then what will happen if the program is run again for the 3rd time? Trying to rename abc to abc_archived will give an error since another file with the same name will be present already. How do you plan to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you for bringing up a great point. I see where this process goes wrong when the file is saved multiple times on the same day. The goal is to rename old versions of files and not overwrite them. If the file is saved multiple times on the same day what is the best way to rename/store them so they are saved and distinguishable from other versions? i thought about using the timestamp of the file or someone mentioned the possibility to use 'soft links'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file has already been removed by the time it goes to rename it. If you remove the `os.remove(model_loc)` call, that should fix it.

Comment: I removed the os.remove(model_loc) but get following error:
"Windows Error: [Error 183] A file can not be created, if it already exists"

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the root cause. If you catch any exception, then you could hide the actual cause.

```
if os.path.exists(model_loc):    
    try:
        os.rename(model_loc,  model_name + '_archived')  <-- wrong
    except:
        os.remove(model_loc)                             <-- wrong
        os.rename(model_loc, model_name + '_archived')   <-- wrong
        with open(model_loc, 'wb') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(scoring_model, pfile)
```

For example, if the exception is the file does not exists. Why do you try to remove it and then rename it? You cannot rename a file that does not exists. And you should not remove a file that does not exists.

That said. You should just create the file.

Anyhow, if you want to rename the file and store in the same directory than `model_name`, you have to explicitly say so to `os.rename`. Otherwise, `os.rename` will try to *move* the file to the current directory (wherever the script is running).

```
if os.path.exists(model_loc):    
    try:
        target = os.path.join(dest, model_name + '_archived')
        os.rename(model_loc, target)
    except:
        with open(model_loc, 'wb') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(scoring_model, pfile)
```

Although, you should try to catch the right exception. Here we are still catching everything.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up with 'target'. i added the code `with open(model_loc, 'wb')...` below the `os.rename(...)` to make it work. I also ended up adding the timestamp to the file name to distinguish the different versions.